# AWS Glue: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm getting this error when using AWS Glue crawlers:

> [xyz] ERROR : Not all read errors will be logged.
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied
> (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
> Request ID: xyz; S3 Extended Request ID: xyz; Proxy:
> null), S3 Extended Request ID: xyz

I have S3FullAccessRole and all Glue roles enabled.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide more details, e.g. crawler configuration + IAM Role configuration?

Comment: @RobertKossendey Crawler security was configured through the Glue console. IAM: I have S3FullAccess, AWSGlueServiceRole, AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole, AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess, CloudWatchLogsReadOnlyAccess. Not sure if that fully answers your question but I have all the main permissions required.

Comment: The glue role must have s3 permissions, not you as an IAM user.

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean? I have AWSGlueServiceRole activated. Doesn't that allow AWS Glue to access S3?

Comment: yes as Marcin mentioned, you have to add S3 permissions to the IAM role that you are configuring to run the glue jobs.  Please follow principle of least privilesges for s3 permission, and wherever possible.

Comment: I added s3 permission to AWSGlue role generated and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add the S3 permissions to your created AWSGlue role. Not to the policy but the role.